# MDaemon service stops unexpectedly

Tags: windows-server-2008

My MDaemon service stops Unexpectedly,who can helps me?

I start it and test my account in Outlook,everything seem to be ok, but after 3-5 min testing account settings goes to error and doesn't respond.
I refer to MDaemom service ,its status is "started" , but when click on this service the "start" option  is Eligible!

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check your MDaemon-System.log file, located in the MDaemon/Logs directory. Do you see anything that shows that the service was stopped unexpectedly? If you remove the MDaemon system service via Setup | System Service, then run MDaemon as an application by clicking MDaemon.exe in the MDaemon/App directory, does the issue persist? If the issue goes away, then try reinstalling the service via the Setup menu & relaunch MDaemon & see if that fixes the issue. Also, make sure you do not have any third-party antivirus software scanning the MDaemon directory, as this can sometimes lead to issues. If the issue persists after taking these measures, then our support staff would need to analyze crash dumps from your server. If that's the case, then you would want to get in touch with them via this link:
http://www.altn.com/Support/RequestSupport/

You can also submit your question to the Alt-N forums. Many of our experts and support staff monitor these forums, so they would also be a great resource for you. You can access them here:

http://www.altn.com/Support/CommunityForums/